# microtype font expansion and DVI output; problem with kpathsea

Tags: fonts, microtype, dvi, font-expansion

Consider the following file `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion]{microtype} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A new chapter}
Some actual testing text here. Let us make this long enough so that it
will run over at least one line so I can test to see if protrusion is
the problem. Ha Ha Ha.!!
\end{document}
```

If I process it with `pdflatex`, the file generates just fine. If I try to process it with `pdflatex -output-format dvi`, it fails with

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1095+20
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095+20
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (Web2C 2009)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1095+20
! I can't find file `ecrm1095+20'.
<*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095+20

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095+20

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1095+20.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095+20' failed to make ecrm1095+20.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font csnameendcsname=ecrm1095+20 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file n
ot found.
```

If I set the option `expansion=false` to `microtype`, the DVI output compiles just fine.

Questions:

> (a) Is this normal, and is there a good explanation why DVI output breaks while PDF output works? (b) Can this be fixed? or is font expansion something I just shouldn't play with in DVI output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pdftex` is capable of producing both `pdf` and `dvi` output. But font expansion is a feature that belongs to solely `pdf` and therefore is not (immediately) available in `dvi`. See section 3.5 of [the `microtype` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf).

According to that same manual `microtype` should be able to realize it's used in a `dvi` context, or maybe it *does* depend on on the `DVIoutput` switch or `\pdfoutput=0` command. Either way, you're not going to get the full capacity of `microtype` in `dvi`.

Comment: Ah. somehow I missed that part of the manual. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From page 27 of the microtype documentation:

> *[A]utomatic* font expansion only works
>   when running pdfTeX in PDF mode.
>   Although expansion is also possible in
>   DVI mode, it requires that all
>   instances of the expanded fonts exist
>   on your TeX system.

So (a) this is the expected default behaviour with DVI and (b) fixing it is possible, but probably not worth the trouble.