# Why does microtype cause auto-pst-pdf to run slowly?

Tags: microtype, auto-pst-pdf

I have a build process using pdflatex that had been working fine (and reasonably fast) until I added `auto-pst-pdf` in order to process some EPS figures. Doing this causes rendering to slow down and generates error messages:

```
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
entering extended mode

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr10+20
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10+20
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2011)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf cmr10+20

! I can't find file `cmr10+20'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10+20

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10+20

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: cmr10+20.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10+20' failed to make cmr10+20.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr10-20
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10-20
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2011)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf cmr10-20

! I can't find file `cmr10-20'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10-20

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10-20

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: cmr10-20.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input cmr10-20' failed to make cmr10-20.tfm.
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
```

Even for a minimal file using the `article` class (see MWE), I see a few such messages. For a file of any complexity, and using more complex document classes, I see many dozens, resulting in rendering times that are unacceptable, and, in some instances, time-outs and pdflatex crashes.

Commenting out the line

```
\RequirePackage[protrusion=true,expansion,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true]{microtype}
```

in my document class restores performance and eliminates crashes.

It appears that by turning off `expansion` I can reduce these symptoms, but I don't know why. What do these errors mean? Do they mean that I'm not "really" getting font expansion anyway (perhaps because of some font limitations)? Is there an incompatibility between `microtype` and `auto-pst-pdf`? Is there something I can do to restore performance while still using all the features of `microtype`?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\RequirePackage[protrusion=true,expansion,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Disable microtype for a portion of a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/disable-microtype-for-a-portion-of-a-document).

Comment: Wow!! Surprising that it takes that much time for this complicated document. But, as per the warnings in the log file, if you add `\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}`, it appears to run slightly (not much) faster.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've expanded the question a bit.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3980/7844) is also relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[tracking,kerning,spacing]{microtype}
\fi
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, is it really that simple? Just to be sure I understand what's happening here: I get `microtype` in my document as before, but it just gets skipped on the pass that processes the EPS files, right? (I use `expansion` too, but even adding that back in this seems to work.)

Comment: right ... I suppose that you convert images where expansion isn't really needed

Comment: Yes, I can certainly do without it there.

Answer (score 9):

With `auto-pst-pdf` one step of the compilation generates a `dvi`. So you must be careful to use either only options which works in both modes (`dvi` and `pdf`) or to use `ifpdf` to use different option depending on the mode.

One example of a mode dependant option is `expansion`: In `dvi` output expansion is normally not possible see the documentation of `microtype`.

The best is to remove the `protrusion` and `expansion` option. `microtype` is clever enough to enable the options only in `pdf`-mode when they are sensible.

Comment: So even if I disable `expansion` and `protrusion`, I'll be getting them (on the pdflatex pass)?